# SharePoint 2016 javascript reference 403 forbidden

Tags: 2016, master-page, query-string

This past March we installed a SharePoint 2016 instance on our 2012 server and have been using it without issue for 7 months now. Last week I came into work to find the list views functionally stopped working and noticed the

`_layouts/15/1033/strings.js?rev=k%2FSaOdWtcHDDvsb%2FUFykOA%3D%3DTAG0` file was returning a 403 Forbidden message. The issue seemed to be the querystring contains a crossite scripting constraint. i.e. urlencoding %2F which = /.

So I thought maybe my organization has implemented a firewall rule or something with McAfee. The last SP update was August and server updates were 2 weeks prior. I then noticed the rte textarea box in the forms was not properly enabled and found issue with the img tag having an 'undefined' in the src path.

So I hard coded in the master page the script tag without query string and programmatically corrected the 'undefined'. Today the datepicker.js started having the same issue with the query string.

Why all of a sudden has this materialized? Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Have you recently patched your farm with any security update or CU update?

Comment: As noted the most recent SP updates had been in August. I would assume others may be having the same issue if that was the case. I ran Sept update after this issue started but it did not resolve any of our problems.

Comment: Well, it's happening again. Just applied Oct 2018 update to combat a documented issue and now the sp.js script tag is surfacing with the query string issue.  _layouts/15/sp.js?rev=D%2FugzG0oq3d7HM81QgdWfA%3D%3DTAG0%3D%3DTAG0